# QMediaPlayer - How to obtain metadata from online radio?

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

I'm using QMediaPlayer from Qt 5.1 to play online radio. Some radio stations have extra data like title of playing music. How to get this info from QMediaPlayer? I suppose that it is possible because Amarok player from KDE is using Qt and can show titles.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to media file's URL, then you can call

```
QMediaPlayer::metaData(QMediaMetaData::Title)
```

to get the title.